# Angular2 - Show index column for the table using angular material

Tags: angular

I am implementing the angular material for the table by following the below reference.

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

I am facing one issue to show the index column in the table and I could not get much reference from online.

Please let me know if there is a way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material - Getting index of row in data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143099/angular-material-getting-index-of-row-in-data-table)